# How to tell if or what element if visible in another element

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have a third party application in which I am trying to grab element information from.  I don't have access or want to have access to the third party's core JS engine.

That said, they have a "slideshow" type thing that does not put a specific "current" class on the element when it comes into the main container view.  Some of it is ran by AJAX doing calls through PHP to a DB to get the next object then it dynamically adds the "next" elements to the DOM and within the container, then any objects brought into the DOM are stay, so I can't tell if the current 'visible' element in the container is current via JS.  Or the traditional way using a class or ID.  It also does not hide the element using "display" or "visibility", so I can't grab it by that either.  It only dynamically adds the offset or positioning.

It just uses an 'offset' var and iterates through the offset AND dynamically add positioning negative or positive based off of the next or previous button selection.

Given that I can't get a "current" class or property off of the element and since it is AJAX, I need to grab a property off of the 'current' element, and place it in the 'Send' property of my Google Analytics.   Hence the page name just comes back as the base page name and not the object name.

Is there a way I can grab the current element in the container element's view space?

Current HTML, as you can see, no real identifiers to tell me what the current element is. A bit frustrating.

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="slide" offset="1" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0"><p class="objTitle">Some object title 1</p></div>
   <div class="slide" offset="2" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:1000"><p class="objTitle">Some object title 2</p></div>
   <div class="slide" offset="3" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:2000"><p class="objTitle">Some object title 3</p></div>
   <div class="slide" offset="4" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:3000"><p class="objTitle">Some object title 4</p></div>
   <div class="slide" offset="5" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:4000"><p class="objTitle">Some object title 5</p></div>
 </div>
```

Positioning left is dynamic based on the viewport size.
JS is more complicated and is a complete library, but all I need to know is if the current slide is in the current containers view.  If possible. I thought about using the viewport trick, but technically it is in the viewport, just positioned absolute left or right of the current slide.

Any pointers are helpful.  I know I did not post the JS, it is a bunch of custom libraries.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it change offset value to change the visible slide? If so you can go with ```document.querySelector('.slide[offset="1"])```

Comment: presumably, whichever one is "current" will have the same position value regardless of where it is in the list of divs within container. You'd simply need to calculate that value, then whichever one matches or is closest to it is current. But ideally you should look for a way to hook into their process, see if there' an event or callback you can tie into.

Comment: BülentAkgül, I can't tell which offset it uses at the time because it doesn't set the offset at the time of it's visiblity, they just are set as their offset and say there, but then they aren't updated again, so I can't use it as the determiner.     

KevinB, I thought about doing this too.  I dug through the code a bit and there is not obvious callback, but I guess I can dig into it more.  It ties into a bunch of custom libraries they use to determine their absolute positioning.  I udated my question to show the positioning value, but I will look more into it.  Thanks for the response both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear what you know about the positioning of the actual place the current slide is positioned, but assuming you know something, how about:

- setting up a mutation observer on container
- any new slide that is added, put an intersection observer onto it

either using the intersection observer and/or getting the offsets of all the slides dynamically you should be able to find which slide is actually in view.